# How do I get bubble effects in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get bubble effects in bootstrap like this site has, https://ginger.io/

I am using bootstrap and I want to get the box that says "I'm an INDIVIDUAL living with a chronic condition looking for a stronger connection to my provider, and better care." But I am having trouble figuring out how.

Comment: The sample you posted is using flash to get that effect.  While it is completely possible to emulate without flash, you do this via CSS...not bootstrap.

Comment: Y do u need a bootstrap component to create such component? You can just make a DIV and give it a little shadow to make it look like that

Comment: Well how do I do that? I am completely new to HTML and CSS

Comment: @phantom there's no flash anywhere on that site, it's all very simple html and css. Hive, do yourself a favor and learn before you build. I recommend teamtreehouse.com.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Wow yes.  I failed sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in my comment, if you don't know how to do this, you should train before you start swinging a hammer. To your specific question: the bubble is simply a white `h3` with a `border-radius` of `10px`, set against a gray background. You can use any block level element, though, not just an h3.

Here's a codepen for example: http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/Kbcex